# DateTime could not be converted to string PDO query

Tags: php, string, datetime

I'm trying add 1 month to a certain date and then save the new
date to the database using the following code. But I seem to get
an error saying "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

```
//New Expiration Date               
$expDate    = new DateTime('2015-06-05');
$expDate->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
$newExpDate = $expDate->format('Y-m-d');

//Extend
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare(' UPDATE users SET valid_until = :new_expire_date WHERE user_id = :user_id ');
$stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $expDate,':new_expire_date' => $newExpDate));
```

The last line is the one that throws the error.
When I `var_dump($newExpDate)`
 I get
`string(10) "2015-07-05"`

It seems wierd to me, I dont know if anyone
has any idea...?
Thank you.

Sorry guys It was a mistake in my query. Im ashamed :(

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `$newExpDate` but there is with `$expDate`

Comment: Consider closing your question then :)

Answer (score 1):

The values passed to [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-parameters) should be [scalars](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) (strings, integers, ...). The first value you pass, `$newExpDate`, is a `DateTime` object.

Use `$expDate->format('Y-m-d');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

$expDate is not a string it is the datetime object.  You have :user_id assigned as $expDate.  I think you meant to do something else here.  $newExpDate is a string and that part of the statement seems to be correct.  Relook at the first element of your created array and make sure that is really what you meant to do.